# Can I create custom rules in StyleCop without coding anything?

Tags: stylecop

Can anybody confirm or deny that I can modify default styles provided by StyleCop by just modifying some configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable rules but if you want to check a custom style, you will have to code your own rules. You may read the API help file of StyleCop.

Answer (score 2):

Creation of new rules requires some C# code. See [here](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html) and [here](http://www.lovethedot.net/2008/05/creating-custom-rules-for-microsoft.html) for some articles on custom rule creation.

You can enable/disable the existing rules with a configuration file. Stylecop comes with the StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe which can be used to edit/generate a xml config file to configure which rules will be run. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643331/disabling-stylecop-rules) on how to disable specific rules.