# Disable StyleCop Rule with VS2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, stylecop, rule

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express and therefore don't have access to the integration for the regular version of VS.  I have used the [MSBuild to integrate StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration) and the rules show up as Warnings.  I want to be able to disable rules.  The [Disabling StyleCop rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643331/2145211) post shows that this is possible but I can't make sense of the answer which suggests to edit the *Settings.StyleCop* file.  However, I don't understand what is required to be added to this file to disable a rule.

If I wanted to disable rule [*SA1649*](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1649.html) for instance how would I update the following file?

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="4.3">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DeprecatedWords">
      <Value>preprocessor,pre-processor</Value>
      <Value>shortlived,short-lived</Value>
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
  <Parsers>
    <Parser ParserId="StyleCop.CSharp.CsParser">
      <ParserSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="GeneratedFileFilters">
          <Value>\.g\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.generated\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.g\.i\.cs$</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </ParserSettings>
    </Parser>
  </Parsers>
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules">
      <AnalyzerSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="Hungarian">
          <Value>as</Value>
          <Value>do</Value>
          <Value>id</Value>
          <Value>if</Value>
          <Value>in</Value>
          <Value>is</Value>
          <Value>my</Value>
          <Value>no</Value>
          <Value>on</Value>
          <Value>to</Value>
          <Value>ui</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </AnalyzerSettings>
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Note:  I am using version 4.7 even though the default settings file shows 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following documentation to [edit a stylecop rule in the XML](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists)

The XML code snippet is below.

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="4.3">
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="StatementMustNotBeOnSingleLine">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementMustNotBeOnSingleLine">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

In addition, I also found out that you can drag the `Settings.Sytlecop` file onto the `StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe` which presents a GUI for enabling and disabling the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below code in notepad and save as settings.StyleCop and place it in solution folder and build

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```